# Can the Python read() command be structured with two input variables?

Tags: python

I've been given some python code (at least I was told it was in python and it doesn't match matlab code structure) to get running and one of the lines is

```
data = f.read(1024x1024, 'int32')
```

I'm getting a syntax error which doesn't surprise me as I thought read() could only take one input and that was size...

I checked the docs https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html
and had a general look around, for example here: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm and here: http://pymbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file.html

There are no indications that read() can take two inputs, nevermind one with a 'x' in it.
(I am also not clear on what the intentions of the 1024x1024 was, which is why I'm questioning if it's python, it looks like they're trying to set the size but it doesn't work like that for the read method)

Does anyone know what I'm missing? (or can work out what was originally meant by the command?)

Whole script section:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
out = open(outfile, 'w')
data = f.read(1024x1024, 'int32')
result = out.write(data[0:256000])
out.closed
f.closed
```

It's basically notes on what they want to happen in a particular section of the script but they wrote it as if it was code and I have no idea what the intention of the data line is.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is probably being downvoted because it shows a [lack of research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). The read method of the Python file object is well documented.

Comment: @Adriaan: Are you sure remove that tag is correct? OP said that *at least I was told it was in python and it doesn't match matlab code structure.*

Comment: I'm aware it's well documented and I use it regularly, I've never seen it used with multiple inputs or anything that indicated that multiple inputs were possible, but I need to understand this to write the code so I wondered if anyone had seen it used like this before or if there was a module that for some reason overwrote the read command? That because I don't have a full script I wouldn't be able to see I am not trying to waste your time and I am sorry you see it like that, I simply ran to the end of my own expertise and hoped someone might have seen this before and be able to clarify. Sorry

Comment: @KevinGuan `f.read` is not valid MATLAB syntax unless there's also a MATLAB class that goes along with the code he was given.

Comment: I guess the first argument is the size and the second is the data type. This does not match the native file object nor the `os.file` syntax and I would bet it is not Python, but I can't tell just from one line.

Comment: @PauloScardine I'll add the other lines to the main question

Comment: @KevinGuan I am sure. He says that he was told it was python. Period. Next part: "code structure  doens't match MATLAB", which he thought of by himself judging the grammatical structure. So it's like tagging this question as JAVA or C#, because the code structure doesn't match one of those languages either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks more like pseudocode than anything; specifying `"int32"` makes me think they are reading from a binary file. You probably need something like

```
import numpy as np

def load_array(filename, dtype="int32", shape=(1024,1024)):
    return np.fromfile(filename, dtype).reshape(shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error has nothing to do with the read "command". Syntax error means that the interpreter/parser couldn't make sense of what you're writing at all. When that happens in python it will normally point at what's confusing the interpreter, fx:

```
    data = f.read(1024x1024, 'int32')
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note the `^` pointing at `1024x1024` which is the fault, it simply doesn't understand what `1024x1024` is (so it won't get to the point to actually try to call the `read` method). If you meant to multiply the numbers you should have written `1024*1024` instead.

When you change to `1024*1024` you'll get other errors (for not reading the documentation for `read` - it doesn't take those arguments).

As for the language I'd suspect that there's no sane language with such a construct. The problem here is that `x` doesn't work well as a multiplication operator since that would be problematic with things like `axe` (did he mean `a*e` or the variable named `axe`?). It looks more like it's pseudo code.

Comment: But...`TypeError: read() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`.

Comment: Perhaps this is not Python after all.